# SUR regression (which fails for too big in R) has identical variables, so is mostly multiple OLS; does error term effects matter?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I originally posted this to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and was advised by [I_O](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/356408/i-o) that the question would be appreciated more here. I am not sure how to reformat this to be appropriate here, so I am copying it over for now:

Before I get into the problem, I want to acknowledge that I have seen that [there is a previous question that has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259244/r-sur-regression-using-systemfit-resulting-in-error-lu-computationally-singular), and it gave me an idea for a work around for getting the regressions together for presentation, but I am still somewhat worried about the differences in standard error, since I intend to include the confidence interval. I also want to know whether what I want to do is actually possible or if there was something wrong on my end that I have overlooked, and I also want to understand more about the function/package in any event.
The actual code I was trying to run was basically basically as follows, on a dataset of nearly 22000 anonymized patients with cost and demographic data, and dividing up the :

```
systemfit::systemfit(formula = list(
     TotalCost = Cost_Total_After - Cost_Total_Before ~ gender + AgeGroup + ethnicity + Other_Demographics + Whether_has_certain_medical_condition,
     Cost.EmergencyMed = Cost_EM_After - Cost_EM_Before ~ gender + AgeGroup + ethnicity + Other_Demographics + Whether_has_certain_medical_condition,
     Cost.GeneralMed = Cost_GM_After - Cost_GM_Before ~ gender + AgeGroup + ethnicity + Other_Demographics + Whether_has_certain_medical_condition,
     Cost.MentalHealth = Cost_MH_After - Cost_MH_Before ~ gender + AgeGroup + ethnicity + Other_Demographics + Whether_has_certain_medical_condition,
     Cost.NeurologyAndPain = Cost_NeuroPain_After - Cost_NeuroPain_Before ~ gender + AgeGroup + ethnicity + Other_Demographics + Whether_has_certain_medical_condition,
     Cost.PhysRehab = Cost_PR_After - Cost_PR_Before ~ gender + AgeGroup + ethnicity + Other_Demographics + Whether_has_certain_medical_condition,
     Cost.SensoryHealth = Cost_SensoryH_After - Cost_SensoryH_Before ~ gender + AgeGroup + ethnicity + Other_Demographics + Whether_has_certain_medical_condition,
     Cost.SpecialtyMedicine = Cost_SpecialtyMed_After - Cost_SpecialtyMed_Before ~ gender + AgeGroup + ethnicity + Other_Demographics + Whether_has_certain_medical_condition,
     Cost.Surgery = Cost_Surgery_After - Cost_Surgery_Before~ gender + AgeGroup + ethnicity + Other_Demographics + Whether_has_certain_medical_condition 
 ),   
 method = "SUR",   
 data = droplevels(patientCost) )
```

The actual resulting error is

> Error in .solve.dgC.lu(as(a, "dgCMatrix"), b = b, tol = tol) : 
>   LU computationally singular: ratio of extreme entries in|diag(U)| = 4.666e-20

Additional information is that I have done a SUR *almost **identical*** to this, but the dependent variable was based on number of healthcare encounters instead of costs, *and that SUR completed successfully with no error*. The only difference I can think of for that is that the numbers must be lower. This means that one hypothesis I had, that it was being thrown off through something similar to multicollinearity or such because of the fact that the total cost difference is based on the sum of the pre- and post- costs added up to those in the `TotalCost` equation. (This was a legitimate problem I had in earlier attempts which I have since corrected.)

Since the predictor variables are all identical in each of the functions within the SUR, they are all effectively OLS regressions, so I am able to solve the immediate problem by tacking on a basic `lm(Cost_Total_After - Cost_Total_Before ~...)` to the SUR  without that first formula.
I still would like more insight into what may be going wrong and how I can improve things going forward on this. I am also somewhat concerned that the confidence intervals may be affected. Would that measure be meaningfully thrown off by my strategy? If it is, how  should I deal with it?
If this whole thing is presented confusingly, I apologize, I am new to actually participating on the site, and am still figuring things out. I can't think of a way to create sample data for you that is close enough to mine that you could use to duplicate it. If you want to try doing so on you own, most of the demographic variables, including `AgeGroup` and `ethnicity` are categorical variables in `factor` or `character` format, though at least one is a `logical` 'yes/no' thing, as is `Whether_has_certain_medical_condition` (not what I actually named it).
If you need any more information, I can try to help answer that for you.

Comment: [Cross posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71860066/r-sur-regression-with-systemfit-gets-error-lu-computationally-singular-ratio-o) from stack overflow on the advice of @I_O.

Comment: There is a lot of text here. Could you state/explain at the start the actual question in a few sentences (but less cryptical than the current title). That makes it more easy to read the rest.